# Alternatives for Dragon Naturally Speaking

Tags: windows, audio, dragon-naturallyspeaking

Are there any good ones out there? I love their software, but their support is PISSING ME OFF.

I'm jumping hoops and circles just so I can get access to the app download but they still haven't given it to me. I've spoken to 3 departments already. Ugh.

*update*

More background:
I'm a college student/blogger who always writes. I just need an accurate software that will transcribe speech to text. I haven't found a free version that is as good as dragon.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Comment: There is no good replacement (Microsoft speech recognition isn't as good yet though you may want to try), aside from Google speech recognition only available in Gdocs and a few restricted websites :( On OS X, you could use Apple speech recognition. On Linux, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/256138/16704

Answer (score 4):

There are other companies the best one among them is

https://mmodal.com/

The software is as good as Dragon and less costly.

Microsoft also provides this feature, but its not as good.

[Microsoft Voice to Text](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-the-Speak-text-to-speech-feature-459e7704-a76d-4fe2-ab48-189d6b83333c)

Comment: "The software is as good as Dragon" -> your personal experience?

Comment: Hi Franck it's as good as Dragon, I have used both.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. It seems to be specialized for medical records though. Some discussion at https://www.knowbrainer.com/forums/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=4&threadid=20466

Comment: Its fully commercial product but they have integrated with software's like EPIC so that healthcare professionals can record medical records. But it can be used as good outside Medical domain also.